# Cannot get the previous url from constructor in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

Able to get the previous url in the constructor by subscribing to router events. Logged and checked in constructor but, when clicking on back, button unable to get it into the method.

Constructor:

```
previousUrl: string;

 constructor(
    private router: Router,
   ) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
        pairwise()
      ).subscribe((e: any) => {
        this.previousUrl = e[0].urlAfterRedirects;
        console.log('this is it' + this.previousUrl); // previous url
    });
  }
```

goBack():

```
 goBack() {
      console.log('******************************' + this.previousUrl);
      this.router.navigate([ this.previousUrl ]);
   }
```

Comment: Do you mean the back button in your browser? Or a `<button>` with `(click)="goBack()"`?

Comment: @Korfoo Yes it is   <button mat-icon-button (click)="goBack()"><mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon></button>

Comment: Can you please show me all code of .ts file ?

Comment: What get's logged by `console.log('******************************' + this.previousUrl);`? Is it the url you want? Or the same route you are on?

Comment: @korfoo it is undefined